# How I can add 3rd party (C++) dependency to BUCK file?

Tags: c++, build, buck

I build my project with Buck. How can I add external (not Buck) libs to project?

My example BUCK:

```
cxx_binary(
    name="my_project",
    srcs=[
         "my_file.cpp",
    ],
    deps=[
        "boost_system",
        "boost_filesystem",
    ],
    compiler_flags=['-w',
                    '-Ddef',
                    '-Ipath',
                    ])
```

But is error:
BUILD FAILED: //my_proj:my_project: parameter 'deps': cannot coerce 'boost_system' to class com.facebook.buck.model.BuildTarget

Answer (score 1):

Use prebuilt_cxx_library:

```
prebuilt_cxx_library(
    name="boost_system",
    lib_dir='../otherlibs'
)

prebuilt_cxx_library(
    name="boost_filesystem",
    lib_dir='../otherlibs'
)
```

and

```
........
deps=[
    ":boost_system",
    ":boost_filesystem",
],
.......
```

Comment: I would also like to mention that there is a huge collection of C++ Buck ports here: https://github.com/buckaroo-pm/